# Curved flow lines in leaflet minicharts R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm creating a flow map in R Leaflet which will eventually go through Shiny. This is a very simplified example of what it looks like:
[image]

How can I curve the flow lines?

Reproducible example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.minicharts)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  Origin_lat = c(40.15212, 40.65027),
  Origin_lng = c(-74.79037, -74.91990),
  Dest_lat = c(40.78749, 40.78749),
  Dest_lng = c(-73.96188, -73.96188),
  flow = c(237, 84)
)


leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%
  setView(lat = 40.39650, lng = -74.39541, zoom = 9) %>%
  addFlows(
    lng0 = dat$Origin_lng,
    lat0 = dat$Origin_lat,
    lng1 = dat$Dest_lng,
    lat1 = dat$Dest_lat,
    flow = dat$flow
  )
```

Comment: Have you looked into changing from leaflet to mapdeck https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a package geosphere which has the functions which you need

This should get you where you need to be, you can pass it either a matrix for start and stop with X,Y in each or a vector for each type of coordinate, as here
library(geosphere) #install as needed

```
gcIntermediate(c(Origin_lat,Origin_lng), c(Dest_lat,Dest_lng),
               n=80, #how many curve points along lines
               addStartEnd=TRUE,
               sp=TRUE ) %>% 
leaflet() %>% 
addTiles() %>% 

addPolylines()
```

If it were me, I would restructure the points to be able to pass: origin & destination as two-column matrices of Lat, Lon values, but it should work as vectors too.